# Blocking 127.0.0.1 in iptables?

Tags: firewall, iptables

I'm in the process of setting up some rules for iptables. Not wanting to make any errors I am currently only logging activity. The logs have shown a number of entries  for 127.0.0.1 hitting my rules:

```
Dec 29 13:55:54 ns305520 kernel: [NETFILTER] IN=lo OUT= MAC=00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:08:00 SRC=127.0.0.1 DST=127.0.0.1 LEN=70 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=30767 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=58432 DPT=53 LEN=50
```

I don't know what this activity actually is.

Can someone tell me, would 127.0.0.1 typically be whitelisted in iptables? And are there any other considerations that you would recommend taking?

Comment: 127.0.0.1 is you... Hopefully you can ping yourself at all times.?

Comment: Yes. I am seeking advice on how 127.0.0.1 is handled. Is this typically put on a whitelist? I assumed localhost would be ignored in the firewall.

Comment: In general I would say yes, if you can't reach the localhost address it makes life hard for certain things the localhost is a loopback through the machine's own TCP stack so should be safe... But for the sake of a random bit of information: It has been blocked before by firewalls, although mistakenly: https://kc.mcafee.com/corporate/index?page=content&id=KB66159

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already said by other, 127.0.0.1 is you and you should not block it, it is necessary.

The log line you provide in your question shows also that the packet came through a specific interface: the `lo` (loopback) interface (you can see all your interfaces with a command like `ifconfig`).

For whitelisting your own box, you should allow everything that goes through this `lo` interface:

```
iptables -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
```

This answer is taken from what can be found in a paper by Jan Engelhardt called [Towards the perfect ruleset](http://inai.de/docs). It is quick to read, and contains more information about the loopback / 127.0.0.1

Answer (score 3):

Usually loopback connection enabled in firewall. Complete disabling it can make many troubles.
For example, Your logged packet is DNS request to local DNS server. If block it, then DNS can stop work.